# FeathersJS timeout error when retrieving multiple data in database

Tags: mongodb, feathersjs

now that i have more than 300 data in my database (mongoDB) , my feathersjs services (e.g. 'customers' service) are now throwing error ():

```
Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling customers::find
at client.js:87
```

I'm using feathers-mongoose to connect to mongoDB and react js as frontend. here's a sample code of how i call feathers services :

```
const app = feathers(); app.service('customers').find().then((data) => {console.log(data)}).catch((err) => {console.log(err);})
```

Comment: Please show some code of what you're doing.  Are you using feathers-mongoose or calling mongo directly?  Are you passing parameters to `find`?

Comment: @Joe is this enough? i updated my question. thanks

Comment: First I recommend to make sure that the client and server version are the same. The error message appears to be coming from an older Feathers client version.

Comment: but when i search fewer data, it does not throw errors @Joe

Comment: @Daff I see that error sometimes even in the current socket.io client.